# JS question "i dont know why i am getting a different answer"

Tags: javascript

let a = 10;

let b = "20";

let c = 80;

console.log(--c + +b + --a * +b++ - +b * a + --a - +true);

**I think I should get 108 then multiple it by -1 then multiple it by 16 which should result in -1728 however I am getting an answer of 97!!!!

how is that possible?

when I broke the problem into 3 pieces (--c + +b + --a)(+b++ - +b)(a + --a - +true) the computer agreed with me that the first part should be 108 then -1.

I need help guys. someone explain it to me, please.

THANKS**

Comment: Why have you raised the tags python, java and C++ for the JS quesion?

Comment: Multiplication before addition/subtraction! These are the correct braces: `--c + +b + (--a * +b++) - (+b * a) + --a - +true` and with the values filled in `79 + 20 + (9 * 20) - (21 * 9) + 8 - 1` and suddenly `97` makes sense

Answer (score 2):

This is because of order/preference of operations.
as multiplication has higher preference than addition and subtraction.

just put bracers like below it will give required output (-1728).

```
console.log((--c + +b + --a) * (+b++ - +b) * (a + --a - +true));
```

Comment: indeed this is how the statement gets evaluate

    --c = 79 //value of c is now 79
    +b = 20 //value of b remains '20'
    --a = 9 //value of a is now 9
    +b++ = 20 //value of b is now 21
    a = 9
    --a = 8 //value of a is now 8
    +true = 1
    console.log(--c + +b + --a * +b++ - +b * a + --a - +true) //is evaluated to
    console.log(79 + 20 + 9 * 20 - 21 * 9 + 8 - 1) //97